# Retrieving data from a generic type

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following interface which can be implemented by custom controls and forms:

```
public interface IThemeable<T> where T : ITheme
{
    T Theme { get; set; }

    void ChangeTheme(); // Calls ThemeChangedEvent
}
```

`ITheme` is an interface that all themes inherit from:

```
public interface ITheme : ICloneable
{
    Color ThemeColor { get; set; }
}
```

I want `IThemeable` components to be able to inherit the Parent theme's `ThemeColor` if the Parent is also an `IThemeable`, so I made an interface to provide this functionality:

```
public interface IThemeableComponent
{
    bool InheritTheme { get; set; }
    ITheme ParentTheme { get; set; }

    void InitializeTheme();
}
```

Inside `InitializeTheme` is where I would set `ParentTheme`, so I ideally want to check if the component's parent inherits from `IThemeable` and if so, set `ParentTheme` to the parent's theme. However, because IThemeable requires a generic type, I can't do this:

```
// Expander.cs - class Expander : ContainerControl, IThemeable<ExpanderTheme>, IThemeableComponent

private bool _inheritTheme;
public bool InheritTheme
{
    get
    {
        return _inheritTheme;
    }
    set
    {
        // Check whether the parent is of type IThemeable
        _inheritTheme = Parent.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IThemeable<>) && value;
    }
}

public ITheme ParentTheme { get; set; }

public void InitializeTheme()
{
    Theme = Themes.ExpanderDefault.Clone() as ExpanderTheme;

    if (Parent.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IThemeable<>))
    {
        ParentTheme = (Parent as IThemeable<>).Theme; // Type argument is missing
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can achieve what I want? Or if not, are there any alternative methods?

**EDIT:**

It's preferred that IThemeable is generic. Implementing members should have a specified theme which extends ITheme, rather than ITheme itself, for two reasons:

1. Themes are changed using the designer. They also use an editor to change the theme. If `ITheme` is used, it would be impossible for the designer to determine the implementing theme that is being used.
2. Code requires knowing more information about the theme in order to render the component correctly, as each theme will have their own unique properties (For example, FormTheme has `Color ControlBoxHoverColor`). If `ITheme` is used, I would need to cast it to the preferred type instead of using code like so:

-

```
// ThemedForm.cs - class ThemedForm : Form, IThemeable<FormTheme>

private FormTheme _theme;

[DisplayName("Theme")]
[Category("Appearance")]
[Description("The Theme for this form.")]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
[Editor(typeof(ThemeTypeEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public FormTheme Theme
{
    get { return _theme; }
    set
    {
        _theme = value;
        ChangeTheme();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you actually _need_ `IThemable` to be generic or is it ok if `Theme` would just be of type `ITheme` instead of `T`? So `IThemable<T>` would just become non-generic `IThemable` thus removing the problem.

Comment: @Mark I edited my question to provide details as to why I'm using generics.

Comment: How about creating a non-generic `IThemable` interface and let the generic `IThemable<T>` inherit from it? This way you can check for the non-generic interface.

Comment: @qqww2 How would I retrieve the Theme from the non-generic `IThemeable`?

Comment: Use it just for checking. Use the generic version elsewhere.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding my question. I can check if something is IThemeable using `GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IThemeable<>)`, what I can't do is get that object's theme using `(Parent as IThemeable<>).Theme`.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I've been overthinking this. Because `ParentTheme` is just `ITheme`, would `ParentTheme = (ITheme)Parent.GetType().GetProperty("Theme").GetValue(Parent);` do the trick?

Comment: Possibly! I'll test that out and let you know the results. Ideally I would like to avoid using reflection, but if it's the only option I guess I can make do with it.

Comment: @Mark Alright, when I try that, I get a `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. I checked if Parent was null, and that was false. I'm calling `InitializeTheme();` inside my OnCreateControl method.

Comment: Strange. Does `Parent.GetType().GetProperty("Theme")` return `null`?

Comment: I fixed it by recursively checking the parent of the controls and returning the first parent which inherits from the `IThemeable<>` type. It works as intended now. Could you make your comment above an answer so that I can mark the question as answered? Thanks :)

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ParentTheme` is just an `ITheme`, the following should do the trick:

```
ParentTheme = (ITheme)Parent.GetType().GetProperty("Theme").GetValue(Parent);
```